# Bar plots in sans serif font

Tags: fonts, pgfplots, luatex, fontspec

I want to typeset my bar plots with a sans serif font (using LuaTeX). I tried many options that I found searching the manual and the internet. None of them solved my problem---using different fonts than CM; with CM it works!

The same MWE shows different results in the PDF depending on the engine (PDFTeX vs. LuaTeX).

MWE MinionPro, MyriadPro, pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{%
  sansmath%
  ,MinionPro%
  ,MyriadPro%
} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
  /tikz/font=\sansmath\sffamily
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xbar,
  xlabel={a--d},
  symbolic y coords={a,b,c,d},
  ytick=data,
  nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (45,a)
    (20,b)
    (1,c)
    (5,d)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Plot:
[image: Bar plot, MinionPro, MyriadPro, pdflatex]

MWE MinionPro, MyriadPro, lualatex

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{%
  sansmath%
} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[%
  BoldFont={MinionPro-Bold}%
  ,ItalicFont={MinionPro-It}%
  ,BoldItalicFont={MinionPro-BoldIt}%
  ,Numbers=OldStyle%
]{MinionPro-Regular}

\setsansfont[%
  Scale=MatchLowercase%
  ,BoldFont={MyriadPro-Bold}%
  ,ItalicFont={MyriadPro-It}%
  ,BoldItalicFont={MyriadPro-BoldIt}%
  ,Numbers=OldStyle%
]{MyriadPro-Regular}
\setmathsf{MyriadPro-Regular}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
  /tikz/font=\sansmath\sffamily
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xbar,
  xlabel={a--d},
  symbolic y coords={a,b,c,d},
  ytick=data,
  nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (45,a)
    (20,b)
    (1,c)
    (5,d)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Plot:
[image: Bar plot, MinionPro, MyriadPro, lualatex]

Here are some of the pgfplotsset options I already tried (and noted down):

```
\pgfplotsset{%
%  ,tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}%
%  ,tick style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}
%  ,every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}%
%  ,every axis/.style={font=\sansmath\sffamily}%
%  ,xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\sansmath\tick}$}%
  ,/tikz/font=\sansmath\sffamily
%  ,legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}%
%  ,label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}%
}
```

Best regards
Christoph

Comment: Not an answer, but if a deadline is looming could you generate the image in a `standalone` document, and then include the image for the `LuaTeX` run?

Comment: @cmhughes Good idea! But I did not have a working solution for PDFTeX (numerics were printed italic) since sebschub posted his solution.

Answer (score 6):

Do you use the `MinionPro` and `MyriadPro` versions from [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/) with `pdflatex`? With these packages, you do not need `sansmath`, it is already incorporated in `MdSymbol` which is needed by `MyriadPro`. The following set-up works with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[sansmath]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
  /tikz/font=\mathversion{sans}\sffamily
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xbar,
  xlabel={a--d},
  symbolic y coords={a,b,c,d},
  ytick=data,
  nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (45,a)
    (20,b)
    (1,c)
    (5,d)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: sans serif figure]

Comment: No, I use the fonts provided with Adobe Reader with LaTeX support from http://developer.berlios.de/projects/minionpro. MyriadPro.sty provided by this project does not know the sansmath option. Do your files support the fonts from Adobe Reader?

Comment: @typokurz My scripts are based on the project you mentioned and work well with any version of the fonts. I don't provide prepared metrics, though, so one has to use the ``bash`` scripts to create them. My ``MinionPro.sty`` is very similar to the original one, only small bug fixes and extensions. I'm sure, however, that the original MinionPro project doesn't provide any support for Myriad Pro. My MyriadPro support offers features similar to the ones of MinionPro including proper maths support and the functionality to use two different maths fonts in one document (with the setup above).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But maybe there's somebody else with a solution for LuaTeX?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by Herbert [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88954/10682) using the `unicode-math` package and `\setmathfont`. Another approach was offered by egreg [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88962/10682) by changing the mathcode of the digits.