# unicode-math and sans serif font with LuaTeX and MacTeX

Tags: math-mode, pgfplots, luatex

Using `unicode-math` I was able to use a sans serif font with LuaTeX in math-mode in `pgfplots`. It still works with TeXLive 2016 but it doesn't with MacTeX 2017 and 2018.

Solution to my [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88952/10682):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[%
  BoldFont={MinionPro-Bold}%
  ,ItalicFont={MinionPro-It}%
  ,BoldItalicFont={MinionPro-BoldIt}%
  ,Numbers=OldStyle%
]{MinionPro-Regular}
\setsansfont[%
  Scale=MatchLowercase%
  ,BoldFont={MyriadPro-Bold}%
  ,ItalicFont={MyriadPro-It}%
  ,BoldItalicFont={MyriadPro-BoldIt}%
  ,Numbers=OldStyle%
]{MyriadPro-Regular}  
\setmathfont{MyriadPro-Regular}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xbar,
  xlabel={a--d},
  symbolic y coords={a,b,c,d},
  ytick=data,
  nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (45,a)
    (20,b)
    (1,c)
    (5,d)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On TeXLive 2016 it results in the following plot:

[image: pgfplot with Myriad Pro]

On MacTeX 2017 and 2018 it results in the following plot that uses Latin Modern Math for x ticks and nodes:

[image: pgfplot with Latin Modern Math]

Any ideas where these differences result from?

Comment: Do you receive any complaints that some font was not found (and got replaced)?

Comment: On both distributions (TeXLive and MacTeX) fontspec warns that MyriadPro-Regular does not contain script 'Math' and that OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (ssty) is not available for font MyriadPro-Regular.

Comment: I see. I think it is fair to say that this is not a problem with pgfplots then. Most likely you could work around it by typesetting the ticks and `nodes near coords` in text mode rather than math mode.

Comment: It would be great if this was possible. But even after consulting pgfplots.pdf I don't know how to achieve it. I even thought this was impossible … Doesn't `nodes near coords` need `\pgfmathprintnumber` to properly interpret `\pgfplotspointmeta`?

Comment: `\pgfmathprintnumber` is not necessarily in math mode. See e.g. on p. 75 how to set the options for the ticks globally.

Comment: I am sorry I can't really help here. I simply do not have the fonts installed so I cannot test.

Comment: I deleted my comment, but there are two issues here. WIth TL 2018 I get lm-sans in the plot, not Myriad Pro. But I don't get roman for the numbers or the X axis (only the Y axis). So the plot looks like your 2016 plot. With TL 2017 I get your second plot (roman).

Answer (score 1):

Using a text font as math font is simply wrong.

If your ticks allows it the simplest solution is to type the ticks in text mode (I use TeX Gyre Heros as I don't have your font):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont[]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true},
  font=\sffamily,
  xbar,
  xlabel={a--d},
  symbolic y coords={a,b,c,d},
  ytick=data,
  nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (45,a)
    (20,b)
    (1,c)
    (5,d)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does not solve the problem with the nodes font. Using Latin Modern Math only for nodes *looks* wrong.